# Autofill field based on location in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I want to create a project where a user drops a point in QGIS within a predefined polygon and one of the fields is automatically completed with the value from a column in that specific polygon.

I have been playing around with relation reference in the field properties but can't get anything to work.

Please help!

Thomas

Comment: I think I actually need to use Value Relation. I've been playing around with the 'within($geometry,...' but with no success as yet....

Answer (score 2):

There is an [AutoFields](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/AutoFields/) plugin released in 2016. For the introduction and general usage, please see the author's plugin homepage [AutoFields plugin for QGIS](http://geotux.tuxfamily.org/index.php/en/geo-blogs/item/333-autofields-plugin-for-qgis).

For your case:

1. Start AutoFields plugin and choose your point layer.
2. Create new field to store `id` field of the overlapping polygon.
3. Insert a custom expression `geomwithin('your_polygon_layer', 'id')`

You would notice `geomwithin()` function has come from [refFunction](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/refFunctions/) plugin.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the plugin refFunction and then the code geomintersects('polygon layer','column to be copied'). 
You have to be sure that the topology is OK without polygon overlapping to avoid errors.

Comment: I agree `refFunction` provides key functionality. In the meantime will you expand your answer a bit to cover auto-filling part of the question? (Maybe using `virtual field`?)