# Auto Fill Field with Value based on Location

Tags: arcgis-desktop, fields-attributes

My Question is the same as this: except I am using ArcGIS 10.5.1
[Autofill field based on location in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/171529/autofill-field-based-on-location-in-qgis)

I do not want to use field calculator, is it possible to have certain fields auto-populate when creating a new feature, with values based on its location?

For example, if a new point is within polygon A, then field 1 = True
if not within polygon A field = false

Default value is not ideal, it does fit my need. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [ArcGIS Attribute Assistant](http://solutions.arcgis.com/shared/help/attribute-assistant/) will do this.  This is a free add-in from Esri that auto-populates fields based on settings and parameters you define.

The Attribute Assistant has a [Location Method](http://solutions.arcgis.com/shared/help/attribute-assistant/documentation/methods-location/) that offers a number of different ways to populate location onto different types of features.

Also the [Intersection Features method](http://solutions.arcgis.com/shared/help/attribute-assistant/documentation/methods-intersecting-features/) for setting value based on one feature intersecting with another feature.